# Is there a way to declare an arrays' size with a variable? language: C++

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I want to learn if there is a way to declare an array's size using a variable. It gives an error when I try to do it. For instance here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    int list[x];
}
```

I want to do it because I want the user to decide the array's size.
If there is a way to do it, can you teach me?
thanks in advance...

Comment: No, but vectors are preferred over C-arrays. Consider using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

variable length arrays (VLAs) are not standard C++. Which means it is not portable and it will definitely break on certain systems.
Use `std::vector` instead if you don't know the size at compile time.

Comment: Ok thanks =) the comment was for another answer but the answer was deleted I guess

Comment: @Aldin322 Some compilers support VLAs as an **extension**, it's still not valid C++

Comment: Ok thanks =) the comment was for another answer but the answer was deleted I guess